# javax.jms.ExceptionListener vs try {} catch (JMSException) {}

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, activemq-classic

I'll try to be as detailed as possible. That said, this is my first post so please feel free to be critical of the form/structure/whatever, thanks!

I'm implementing a `MessageListener` (`javax.jms.MessageListener`) and when I began, my IDE (Netbeans) requested I set an `ExceptionListener`. Code something like:

```
public class MessageQueueListener implements MessageListener
{
  public void run()
  {
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(<ActiveMQ-address>);
   Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
   connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener()      
   {
      @Override
      public void onException(JMSException jmse)
      {
          //Handle Exception
      } 
    });

    Session session = _connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("NotificationMessageQueue");
    Consumer consumer = _session.createConsumer(destination);
    consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    connection.start();
  }
}
```

I didn't think much of it at the time, as it makes sense to set a listener for potential connection issues. However as I continued with my implementation, I added `try/catch` statements on secondary methods that are more specific to my use case.

For example:

```
public boolean postNotification(Message message)
{
    String urlParameters = "dummy=dummy";

    try
    {
        postRequest(urlParams); //Below
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException mfe)
    {
       //Handle Exception
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        String eMessage = ioe.getMessage();
        if(eMessage.contains("401"))
        {
             //Handle Exception
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void postRequest(String urlParams) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
        URL url = new URL(<url-to-post-to>);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedLogin);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        con.disconnect();
}
```

Anyways, now my `run()` method is requesting a `try/catch` and the `ExceptionListener` at the beginning of the project is no longer useful.  Using `try/catch`es everything seems to work well, so I'm curious as to what changed. I've tried to discover the reason on my own, but have no luck.

So all of this is context to ask: What is the difference between using an `ExceptionListener` vs `try/catch`es? And is there an advantage to using one or the other, at least with regard to an implementation like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try/catch` is one of the fundamental Java constructs. It is used for handling unexpected errors. So, you'll gonna use [`try/catch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)  a lot:

> You associate exception handlers with a try block by providing one or
>   more catch blocks directly after the try block. No code can be between
>   the end of the try block and the beginning of the first catch block.
>
> try {
>
> } catch (ExceptionType name) {
>
> } catch (ExceptionType name) {
>
> }
>
> Each catch block is an exception handler and handles the type of
>   exception indicated by its argument. The argument type, ExceptionType,
>   declares the type of exception that the handler can handle and must be
>   the name of a class that inherits from the Throwable class. The
>   handler can refer to the exception with name.

On the other hand [`ExceptionListener`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html) is a specific only for JMS :

> If a JMS provider detects a serious problem with a Connection object,
>   it informs the Connection object's ExceptionListener, if one has been
>   registered. It does this by calling the listener's onException method,
>   passing it a JMSException argument describing the problem. An
>   exception listener allows a client to be notified of a problem
>   asynchronously. Some connections only consume messages, so they would
>   have no other way to learn that their connection has failed.
>   A JMS provider should attempt to resolve connection problems itself
>   before it notifies the client of them.

In your case you'll have to use both `try/catch` and `ExceptionListener`. `ExceptionListener` is JMS specific and so you will not use it much. `try/catch` is a fundamental for Java.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and by implementing both try/catches and the Listener my service is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't alternatives. A consumer needs an `ExceptionListener` because it is a `MessageListener,` and doesn't call any methods on the connection, and therefore has no other way of knowing that a connection has failed. However when you call a method that throws a checked exception, you have to catch it. The compiler makes you.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is succinct and helpful.